# mint method usage in ERC721 token implementation

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, nft

What does the internal method call _mint(msg.sender, tokenId) really do in the background when used with ERC721 token implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the [open-zeppelin implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol) of ERC721:

#### _mint() function

```
  /**
   * @dev Internal function to mint a new token
   * Reverts if the given token ID already exists
   * @param to The address that will own the minted token
   * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be minted by the msg.sender
   */
  function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
    require(to != address(0));
    _addTokenTo(to, tokenId);
    emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
}
```

Here it checks that the `to` address isnt the `0x0` address, and then calls the `_addTokenTo` function.

#### _addTokenTo() function

```
  /**
   * @dev Internal function to add a token ID to the list of a given address
   * @param to address representing the new owner of the given token ID
   * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be added to the tokens list of the given address
   */
  function _addTokenTo(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
    require(_tokenOwner[tokenId] == address(0));
    _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;
    _ownedTokensCount[to] = _ownedTokensCount[to].add(1);
}
```

Here it checks that a token with the same token ID is not already owned by someone else (by checking that it *is* owned by the `0x0` address, which is default). If no one owns that token ID, then it sets the owner of that token ID to the `to` address, and increases the count of owned tokens for that `to` address.

Ultimately these are the steps required to create a new token and assign that token an owner.